# sum every 3 rows of a table

Tags: postgresql, sum, rows, group-by, window-functions

I have the following query to count all data every minute.

```
$sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, date_trunc('minute', date) AS momento
FROM p WHERE fk_id_b=$id_b GROUP BY date_trunc('minute', date) 
ORDER BY momento ASC";
```

What I need to do is get the sum of the count for each row with the count of the 2 past minutes.

```
For example with the result of the $sql query above
|-------date---------|----count----|
|2012-06-21 05:20:00 |      12     |
|2012-06-21 05:21:00 |      14     |
|2012-06-21 05:22:00 |      10     |
|2012-06-21 05:23:00 |      20     |
|2012-06-21 05:24:00 |      25     |
|2012-06-21 05:25:00 |      30     |
|2012-06-21 05:26:00 |      10     |  

I want this result:

|-------date---------|----count----|
|2012-06-21 05:20:00 |      12     |   
|2012-06-21 05:21:00 |      26     |     12+14
|2012-06-21 05:22:00 |      36     |     12+14+10
|2012-06-21 05:23:00 |      44     |     14+10+20
|2012-06-21 05:24:00 |      55     |     10+20+25
|2012-06-21 05:25:00 |      75     |     20+25+30
|2012-06-21 05:26:00 |      65     |     25+30+10
```

Comment: Very tricky with SQL. Can't your application do the work? You have to fetch the rows anyway, and you could do that in the same loop.

Comment: @Parth Bhatt: The edit you approved is clearly asking a different question. Please do not approve such edits.

Comment: @interjay: Sorry my mistake, I interpreted it the wrong way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not so tricky with [`lag()` window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/1897b/1)):

```sql
CREATE TABLE t ("date" timestamptz, "count" int4);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('2012-06-21 05:20:00',12),
('2012-06-21 05:21:00',14),
('2012-06-21 05:22:00',10),
('2012-06-21 05:23:00',20),
('2012-06-21 05:24:00',25),
('2012-06-21 05:25:00',30),
('2012-06-21 05:26:00',10);

SELECT *,
    "count"
    + coalesce(lag("count", 1) OVER (ORDER BY "date"), 0)
    + coalesce(lag("count", 2) OVER (ORDER BY "date"), 0) AS "total"
  FROM t;
```

1. I've double-quoted `date` and `count` columns, as these are reserved words;
2. `lag(field, distance)` gives me the value of the `field` column `distance` rows away from the current one, thus first function gives previous row's value and second call gives the value from the one before;
3. `coalesce()` is required to avoid `NULL` result from `lag()` function (for the first row in your query there's no “previous” one, thus it's `NULL`), otherwise the `total` will also be `NULL`.

Comment: Excellent! I love the concept of window functions but keep forgetting to use them. Have an upvote :-)

Comment: +1 for the right solution. I wrote an answer, because comment is not enough.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a more general solution for the sum of values from current and N previous rows (N=2 in your case).

```
SELECT "date", 
sum("count") OVER (order by "date" ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND current row)
FROM t
ORDER BY "date";
```

You can change N between 0 and "Unbounded". This approach gives you a chance to have a parameter in your app "count of the N past minutes". Also, no need for handling default values if out of bounds.

You can find more on this in PostgreSQL docs ([4.2.8. Window Function Calls](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS))

Answer (score 9):

[@vyegorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11268542/939860) covers it mostly. But I have more gripes than fit into a comment.

1. Don't use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `date` and `count` as identifiers *at all*. PostgreSQL allows those two particular key words as identifier - other than every SQL standard. But it's still bad practice. The fact that you *can* use anything inside double-quotes as identifier, even `"; DELETE FROM tbl;"` does not make it a good idea. The name `"date"` for a `timestamp` is misleading on top of that.
2. Wrong data type. Example displays [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html), not `timestamptz`. Does not make a difference here, but still misleading.
3. You don't need `COALESCE()`. With the [window functions `lag()` and `lead()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) you can can provide a default value as 3rd parameter:

Building on this setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ts timestamp, ct int4);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  ('2012-06-21 05:20:00', 12)
, ('2012-06-21 05:21:00', 14)
, ('2012-06-21 05:22:00', 10)
, ('2012-06-21 05:23:00', 20)
, ('2012-06-21 05:24:00', 25)
, ('2012-06-21 05:25:00', 30)
, ('2012-06-21 05:26:00', 10);
```

Query:

```
SELECT ts, ct + lag(ct, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ts)
              + lag(ct, 2, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS total
FROM   tbl;
```

---

Or **better** yet: use a single `sum()` as window aggregate function with a [custom window frame](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

```
SELECT ts, sum(ct) OVER (ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM   tbl;
```

Same result.
Related:

- [Group by end of period instead of start date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32470043/group-by-end-of-period-instead-of-start-date/32470385#32470385)

Comment: Default value to `lag`/`lead` is a nice one!